# Vue npm run serve starts on random port

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to run Vue on port 8080, but can't get that to work. I just created a brand new project with `vue create .` and ran it with `npm run serve`, which starts the app on a random port.

## First attempt

Run npm run serve without any additional configuration

```
$ npm run serve

> vue-demo@0.1.0 serve /Users/ne/projects/vue-demo
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 4294ms                                                                                                              3:21:35 PM

No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.5.3
Time: 4267ms

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:20415/
  - Network: http://192.168.178.192:20415/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

So first I checked to see if another app is running on that port with `lsof -i :8080` but that gave no results.

## Second attempt

So the second attempt was to force the port via the cli with `npm run serve -- --port 8080`, which still started the app on a random port, but no errors in the browser console.

## Third attempt

Next I tried to configure the application in `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    open: process.platform === 'darwin',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080, // CHANGE YOUR PORT HERE!
    https: false,
    hotOnly: false,
  },
};
```

Which didn't work either and even throws an exception in the browser console:

```
15:25:20.889 :8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1566048320873:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
15:25:20.910 client?81da:172 [WDS] Disconnected!
close @ client?81da:172
15:25:21.982 :8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1566048321978:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
15:25:23.079 :8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1566048323075:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
15:25:25.097 :8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1566048325091:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
15:25:29.151 VM14:1 GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1566048329145 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

## package.json

I added package.json, since I might be missing something here.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same issue! However, what makes it strange is that the last time I called the command (a couple days ago) everything worked fine; it actually was served on port 80. But now, having changed nothing, things are acting up, and I have the same issue as you.

Comment: I think this might be the bug you are experiencing: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4437

Comment: @renspaceyi The related issue seems more https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4452, the problems is link to https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/releases/tag/v1.0.22 that is more recent than issue github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4437

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note: This issue is specific to node-portfinder [v1.0.22](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/releases/tag/v1.0.22). It was resolved in [v1.0.23](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/releases/tag/v1.0.23) that is a retag of v1.0.21.**

This seems a feature in portfinder that used random series to allocate an available port.

Trying:

```
const portfinder = require('portfinder');
portfinder.basePort=8080
portfinder.getPortPromise().then((port) => { console.log(port) })
```

return something like:

> 9567

Even if port 8080 is available.

The behaviour change recently in this [commit](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/commit/eeeaba108cbb63b7934e7e0837b024698e0344ce#diff-8a54d09b8f24635c2b2cc156ac31ed21). Before the port were try increasing from basePort to highestport. It comes with the release [v1.0.22](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/releases/tag/v1.0.22)

**Option1: Patching**

In order to use the port 8080, I patched the file `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js` adding line 322 `portfinder.highestPort  = portfinder.basePort + 1`

```
portfinder.basePort = args.port || process.env.PORT || projectDevServerOptions.port || defaults.port
portfinder.highestPort  = portfinder.basePort + 1
const port = await portfinder.getPortPromise()
```

**Option2: Install portfinder previous to the behaviour change**

Another way to workaround waiting for portfinder/vue-cli to choose a solution is to install old portfinder with :

```
npm install portfinder@1.0.21
```

Comment: That fixed it. Although in my case I had to add it to add it in line 81. Should I report this as an issue in the Github repo? And can you tell me how you patched it? I just added this line in node_modules, but that will obviously break when I do a npm reinstall or when someone else installs the packages.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your line line

Comment: Wow, thanks, reinstalling older version worked! This issue is so fresh, Google didn't show any search results and while creating a new issue on the Github page, found a few hours old bug report of this same problem.

Comment: This issue was [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4452#issuecomment-522837172) no need for workarounds anymore - please update your answer.

Comment: @Eido95: I indicate more clearly that this is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily rollback portfinder by placing

```
"resolutions": {
  "@vue/cli-service/portfinder": "1.0.21"
}
```

in your `package.json` file and run `yarn install` afterwards.

Comment: I had to specify a dev dependency of `"portfinder": "1.0.21"` and run `npm install` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time the error occurred when something is running on the same port. But as you mentioned above you have checked it out and there is nothing on it.

Have you tried to restart or shutdown your system and run the server again if not give it a try some of the time its worked for me.

Secondly it would be help full if you share the object of Scripts in package.json.

I have gone through your issue and found this [article](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary) may be this will help you out. Let me know if the error still exists.

Comment: I just added my full package.json file. Where should I change `Serve` to `devServer`?

Comment: Ok, @JohanVergeer thanks for that. Let me go through it.

Comment: Change `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve` to `"devServer": "vue-cli-service serve"`.