# Serve Vue Cli 3.10.0 Project in a specific port

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

How can I serve Vue CLI project in a specific port always, say `8888`? I tried the following options.

1. Editing the serve script in `package.json` to `vue-cli-service serve --port 8888`
2. Updating the `devServer` option in `vue.config.js`. I modified the same to

   `devServer: {
     port: 8888
   }`
3. Serving project specifying port option in serve command like `npm run serve -- --port 8888`

None of the above mentioned steps brought me a luck. Can I know how this to be done in the right way?

Comment: What error did you get
It's working fine for me

vue-cli-service serve --port 8080

Comment: @SyedAfzal No error is getting displayed, instead its serving in some random ports say 56529

Comment: It's a known bug ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4452. See [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4452#issuecomment-522837172) for a solution ~ _"Fixed in portfinder v1.0.23, please delete your lockfile and try install the dependencies again."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue npm run serve starts on random port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536785/vue-npm-run-serve-starts-on-random-port)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your version latest 3.11.0

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I hope it will work for you now

Comment: That was the exact reason. My CLI version was 3.10.